# AWS Lambda Docker Image Environment Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I have a docker image that I want to  be used across a few projects, although each has a different `CMD` entry point.

My Dorckerfile is

```
FROM            public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY            . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY            requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN             pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

WORKDIR         ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD             [ "${CMD}" ]
```

I am attempting to run the image locally with the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html).

Altering the run command to be `docker run -p 9000:8080  -e CMD="src.simulate.orchestrator" lambda:latest`

But I run into the error `Traceback (most recent call last):me: Bad handler '${CMD}': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Any ideas how I can access this environment variable from inside of my Dockerfile?

NOTE: In my debugging I have changed the CMD line to

```
CMD ["src.simulate.orchestrator"]
```

and this works fine, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint `/lambda-entrypoint.sh` does not support a variable as a docker CMD. Instead, it should be simply a static string.
As a workaround, you can use your own ENTRYPOINT
or override the command outside the Dockerfile during the `docker run` invocation.